# Converting Date from API response to Salesforce Date

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I have a string field in an API response (JSON format) which is meant to be a date. The response field is below:

"due":"/Date(1385841600000-0800)/"

How can I convert this to an apex date?

Comment: Can you provide what you believe to be the result of your value?  If this is really Epoch, what is the "-0800" at first glance I would assume it is a time zone (e.g. GMT - 8 or PST) but that conflicts with your response to Mihai Neagoe's offered solution.

Comment: That's very non-JSON-y...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers, what I ended up doing was just taking the value after the open parenthesis and before the timezone offset and then taking the long value and then using date class like ...

```
string due = '/Date(1385841600000-0800)/';
string secs = due.split('\\(')[1].split('\\-')[0];
system.debug(secs);// this outputs '1385841600000' which is the amount of seconds which have passed since beginning of the epoch or 1/1/1970
Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(Long.valueOf(secs));
Date result = dt.date();
system.debug(result);//will output date- in this case it is 2013-11-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe you want the "* 1000" in the previous answer - and you need to convert the epoch string to a Long:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(1385841600000L);
system.debug('got this far: ' + dt.format());
```

outputs:

```
got this far: 11/30/2013 12:00 PM
```

The '-0800' component appears to be a timezone offset, which can be handled using format(): https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_3

Answer (score 0):

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse)

**UPDATE**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(your epoch date * 1000);
```

See [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_Datetime_newInstance.htm) here

Comment: thanks for your quick response, however it's not quite so simple. the response in the date is in a convention known as unix epoch format (which is the amount of milliseconds passed since 1970) and not a generic string. doing what you suggested returns System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: /Date(1385841600000-0800)/.
anon apex code-
string due = '/Date(1385841600000-0800)/';
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(due);
system.debug(dt);

Comment: Updated my answer